# Text file formatting and alignment

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file output.txt which contents would be changed everyday but format would be always like below with:

```
Minimum text string length= 5
Maximum text string length= 22
Maximum numeric string would be only upto 2 digit before and after decimal.
```

**output.txt**

```
OPERATINGSYSTEM SERVER1 SERVER2
Windows    1.36       4.42
Linux12    2.78       5.76
MacOS      3.45       6.39
Ubuntu      4.12       0.00
Android       0.00       3.46
FreePhysicalMemory    30.12      31.65
TotalVisibleMemorySize  48.00      48.00
```

I want to make the content properly alingned and formatted in column as:

```
OPERATINGSYSTEM         SERVER1    SERVER2
Windows                  1.36       4.42
Linux12                  2.78       5.76
MacOS                    3.45       6.39
Ubuntu                   4.12       0.00
Android                  0.00       3.46
FreePhysicalMemory      30.12      31.65
TotalVisibleMemorySize  48.00      48.00
```

I tried below but no output i get:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "spaces=                         "
SET "OPERATINGSYSTEM=MacOS"
SET /a SERVER1=3.45
CALL :formatout
SET "OPERATINGSYSTEM=TotalVisibleMemorySize"
SET /a SERVER1=48.00
CALL :formatout
GOTO :EOF
:formatout
CALL :padright name 15
CALL :padleft size 11
ECHO +%OPERATINGSYSTEM %+%SERVER1%+%SERVER2%
GOTO :eof
:padright
CALL SET padded=%%%1%%%spaces%
CALL SET %1=%%padded:~0,%2%%
GOTO :eof
:padleft
CALL SET padded=%spaces%%%%1%%
CALL SET %1=%%padded:~-%2%%
GOTO :eof
```

**EDIT1**

When **output.txt** is as below:

```
OPERATINGSYSTEM           PROJECTSERVER1 PROJECTSERVER2
Windows        1.36           4.42
Linux12        2.78       5.76
MacOS       3.45       6.39
Ubuntu        4.12       0.00
Android       0.00       3.46
FreePhysicalMemory      30.12      31.65
TotalVisibleMemorySize       48.00      48.00
CPULoadPercentage        2           4
```

I am trying with all the possible combination of spacelength in t1 and t2, but not getting perfectly alinged **newoutput.txt** file as:

```
OPERATINGSYSTEM     PROJECTSERVER1   PROJECTSERVER2
Windows                       1.36             4.42
Linux12                       2.78             5.76
MacOS                         3.45             6.39
Ubuntu                        4.12             0.00
Android                       0.00             3.46
FreePhysicalMemory           30.12            31.65
TotalVisibleMemorySize       48.00            48.00
CPULoadPercentage                2                4
```

**Code i am using:**

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
set "t1=                     "
set "t2=           "
(for /f "tokens=1-3" %%a in (Managed.txt) do (
set "v1=%%a%t1%"&set "v2=%t2%%%b"& set "v3=%t2%%%c"
call echo(%%v1:~0,25%%%%v2:~-14%%%%v3:~-14%%
))>newoutput.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal

    for /f "tokens=1-3" %%f in (output.txt) do call :formatOut %%f %%g %%h 

    endlocal
    exit /b

:formatOut
    setlocal
    set "spaces=                                     "
    set col1=%~1%spaces%
    set col1=%col1:~0,30%
    set col2=%spaces%%~2
    set col2=%col2:~-7%
    set col3=%spaces%%~3
    set col3=%col3:~-7%

    echo %col1% %col2% %col3% 

    endlocal
    goto :EOF
```

To generate file output, call as `formatData.cmd > finalFile.txt`

Comment: where i can add my input text file..?

Comment: for /f "tokens=1,2,3" %%f in (output.txt) do call :formatOut %%f %%g %%h

Comment: output redirection is not working..i am putting '>Newoutput.txt' after 'echo %col1% %col2% %col3%'.

Comment: echo line is executed for each line of output. Using > as redirector, overwrites the file in each execution. Use `( for /f "tokens=1,2,3" %%f in (output.txt) do call :formatOut %%f %%g %%h  )>> newOutput.txt` or redirect the whole batch file as `formatData.cmd > newOutput.txt`

Comment: @MC..its working well but.. 
'OPERATINGSYSTEM         MacOS                                             
TotalVisibleMemorySize'
..rows are being printed secondtime at the end..why so ?

Comment: How are you redirecting the output to the final file?

Comment: as u suggested above '( for /f "tokens=1,2,3" %%f in (output.txt) do call :formatOut %%f %%g %%h )>> newOutput.txt' and in cmd also those lines are coming repeatedly.

Comment: Please. See updated answer. Hope this will clarify. I think you have not seen the `or` in the anterior comment. Lines are read only once, so they should not appear duplicated.

Comment: I've seen it (maybe). The "problematic" line is `( for .... ) >> newOutput.txt` If batch runs twice, and the output file is not deleted before the second run, new generated content is appended to existing file. Deleting the output file before run or changing `>>` with `>` or using the propposed method in answer, any of the three will solve it.

Answer (score 6):

try:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
set "t1=                    "
set "t2=     "
(for /f "tokens=1-3" %%a in (output.txt) do (
    set "v1=%%a%t1%"&set "v2=%t2%%%b"& set "v3=%t2%%%c"
    call echo(%%v1:~0,25%%%%v2:~-8%%%%v3:~-8%%
))>out.txt
```

---

`out.txt`:

```
OPERATINGSYSTEM           SERVER1 SERVER2
Windows                      1.36    4.42
Linux12                      2.78    5.76
MacOS                        3.45    6.39
Ubuntu                       4.12    0.00
Android                      0.00    3.46
FreePhysicalMemory          30.12   31.65
TotalVisibleMemorySize      48.00   48.00
```

Comment: i never thought it could be done in such a small code..nicely working..thanks..!

Comment: @Endoro..Pls see **EDIT1** in question..:)

Comment: @Sunny pls. see my [session protocol](http://i.imagebanana.com/img/ifzerit5/snap044.png).

Answer (score 0):

Install awk from GNU utils, and use this (assuming your info is in file "a"):

```
awk '{printf("%-24s %12s %12s\n",$1,$2,$3)}' a
```

Comment: Mark..AWK is just awesome..but I have to install binary of it on windows for which i am restricted.